# changing text content of a span

Tags: javascript, html

Here is an HTML document. I want to change the text content of this span using javascript:

```
<span class="flip-clock-label">Minutes</span>
```

to :

```
<span class="flip-clock-label">Miliseconds</span>
```

I tried to use childNodes but it seems that I need a hand to find the solution:

Since there are three classes named `flip-clock-label` I can't find a way to select the desired span...

Here is The HTML:

```html
<div class="clock text-center_plans flip-clock-wrapper">
   <span class="flip-clock-divider hours"><span class="flip-clock-label">Hours</span></span>
   <ul class="flip ">
      <li class="flip-clock-before">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">9</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="flip-clock-active">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="flip ">
      <li class="flip-clock-before">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">9</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="flip-clock-active">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <span class="flip-clock-divider minutes"><span class="flip-clock-label">Minutes</span><span class="flip-clock-dot top"></span><span class="flip-clock-dot bottom"></span></span>
   <ul class="flip ">
      <li class="flip-clock-before">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">9</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="flip-clock-active">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="flip play">
      <li class="flip-clock-before">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">1</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="flip-clock-active">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <span class="flip-clock-divider seconds"><span class="flip-clock-label">Seconds</span><span class="flip-clock-dot top"></span><span class="flip-clock-dot bottom"></span></span>
   <ul class="flip play">
      <li class="flip-clock-before">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">1</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="flip-clock-active">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="flip play">
      <li class="flip-clock-before">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">1</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="flip-clock-active">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="up">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="down">
               <div class="shadow"></div>
               <div class="inn">0</div>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What will trigger the change?

Comment: Could you show an example of the javascript you are trying to use to change the text content of span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('flip-clock-label')[1].textContent = 'Miliseconds'
```

But the better way to do this is to use classes that you already have like hours, minutes, seconds, etc. So you can use this one as well:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].textContent = 'Miliseconds'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order is guaranteed you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('flip-clock-label')` and select the one you want... eg `document.getElementsByClassName('flip-clock-label')[2]`. Ideally though, you could add a specific `id` or `class` to the one you want to select to differentiate it from the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can get elements by ids as well, not only by class names.

You can give that span an `id`.

```
<span class="flip-clock-label" id="span1" >Minutes</span>
```

(Each span tag will get a unique id)

Then calling in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("span1").textContent="Milliseconds";`
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an ID for the span, then use `document.getElementById("IdOfSpan").innerHTML = ""` to change the inner HTML. See the sample code below, i used a button as a trigger.

```js
document.getElementById("change").onclick = function() {

document.getElementById("IdOfSpan").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";

}
```

```html
<span class="flip-clock-label" id="IdOfSpan">Minutes</span>

<br><br>
<button id="change">Change</change>
```